# Am I just another person who love mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, research

After spending almost one year on this site, I've realized that my knowledge of mathematics is not deep enough. I love mathematics, i mean I am obsessed with it. I have a masters degree in mathematics from a reputed university in **India** and now I want to pursue PhD in this subject. It's been one year since completion of masters degree and I am unable to find a place in any university for PhD (I failed at couple of entrances). So my question is, is my love and passion for this subject will help me to do research or to do research in mathematics one need an unusual brain? By unusual I mean who can instantly catch the logic and solves a problem, which I can't. I am slow. So I need some advice on this? How should I prepare myself? Thanks.

**Edit:** By this question, I am not asking about which career I should choose. I know I want to do PhD. What I am asking is, "*How one should prepare before starting a PhD?*" What are the basic points I should be working on? Simply just reading many things would not help I guess. So if this question can be reopened and some one give me a pointer then it would be helpful.

Comment: Research is not a matter of quickness. Laurent Schwartz himself said in his autobiography that his mind was slow (or at least he considered that his mind was slow).

Comment: In fact, it is a matter of long time hard working and of having some good ideas from time to time.

Comment: When you say you "failed" at entrance, what does that mean?

Comment: I mean I failed at entrance examinations that one need to pass to get through, for a PhD program.

Comment: I guess I'm not aware of "entrance examinations". Do you by any chance mean PhD qualifying exams?

Comment: Yes PhD qualifying examinations and we often called them entrance exams, because there are few exams conducted nationally, after qualifying, one can apply to some of the prestigious institute in the country.

Comment: I did. Actually I was the first.

Comment: Alright.I hope someone spots it.good luck!

Comment: Sounds like the exams in question play a large role in gaining *admittance* to a PhD program. This is unlike the so called quals/candidacy exams in the US, typically taken after one year of graduate studies. Anyway, for an answer to be useful to you it needs to come from someone who knows your local system. Therefore it is not a good fit to our site. In other words, I agree with closing this as off-topic.

Comment: Did you try Chennai Mathematical Institute (CMI)? They have a qualifying exam too. You can check their website (http://www.cmi.ac.in//) for details. Look at the previous years question papers to get an idea of the depth required.